# How to enable USB debugging for Mi4i from TWRP recovery using ADB?

Tags: android, adb, usb-debugging

I am using Xiaomi Mi4i device and the other day it fell down and the screen broke. It's all blacked out now and the touch is not working. The device is rooted and running stock MIUI ROM. I want to mirror the display onto my computer so that I can take a backup of important files (like contacts and SMS) from my PC. I tried editing some of the .prop files and settings.db using ADB while in TWRP recovery but nothing worked. I think the steps to be followed for Mi devices are slightly different. Can someone guide me through it?

- I am using a Windows 8.1 PC
- "adb devices" from cmd lists the device in recovery mode

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to mirror a display to copy files... `adb pull` works great

Comment: Thanks for the reply @cricket_007.yeah I successfully used adb pull to get my contacts2.db and mmssms.db. But, I was not able to restore messages from mmssms.db . That is why I would like to mirror my display or screencast.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that those databases are encrypted by the way